# Visual Studio Code SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python, function, visual-studio-code, syntax-error

This code does not work on Visual Studio Code but works successfully other interpreters.

```
def functionYogi(a = 200):
    return a
```

Comment: That's valid. As it's unlikely such an obvious parse error exists in VSC, I suspect you haven't accurately reproduced what VSC is trying to parse.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely indentation. Python relies on indentation for functions, loops, classes, etc. You may have indented something incorrectly inside VSCode, resulting in the error.